# Firebase: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'request-promise' simple cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm-request

Wanted to achieve a firebase only approach to a mobile site, so I decided to make a simple API gateway to my app so I call a cloud function endpoint instead of calling my external API and expose my api keys.

I followed the simple hello world example and was ok.

As soon as I added the request-promise module as stated in Google samples (from translate and from url Shortening example) I cannot go forward. because this arises.

```
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'request-promise'
```

tested with 'request' module with same results.

My index.js is really simple

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const request = require('request-promise');

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.wxData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 wwurl = "https://mycurrentendpoint.com/apicall.php?key=1234567890&lat="+request.query.lat+"&lon="+request.query.lon;   
 response.send(wwurl);
});
```

Right now without the  **const request = require('request-promise');** or **const request = require('request');** it deploys ok and display the url to be called.

Really don't know what to do, I already tested creating a new project and just issue this

this is my package.json content:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Is that difficult to implement this in Firebase cloud functions ?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to use an npm module in your Cloud Function, `cd` to the functions directory and run the command `npm install request-promise` or whatever the module is named.  This will add the module to your package.json file.  Then, when you run `firebase deploy`, the module will be available to your code running in Google's cloud.  If you try to use a module that's not listed in package.json, your code will fail.

Comment: Thanks, so request is not a Firebase module, is there a firebase module for this or this is the one ?  Sorry to ask I am new to npm / express

Comment: request-promise is not part of Firebase.  You can use almost any npm module out there, and they all come from different places.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue and fixed it installing both, **request** and **request-promise**. Go to the directory where your functions live and execute:

```
npm install --save request request-promise
```

The --save will take care of updating your package.json. Then redeploy and it should work.

Answer (score 6):

Its not able to find request-promise because it is not installed. It is separate from firebase so you need to add it to your package.json. I would also add the request library.

Add the below two lines in your dependencies and run an npm install.

```
  "request": "^2.x",
  "request-promise": "^1.x"
```

Answer (score 2):

First Change Directory
1) `cd functions`

Next install npm pack
2) `npm install request-promise` //not worked for me, but you can try it.
3) `npm i child-process-promise` //Worked for me fine!
[child-process-promise npm package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise)

Finally you can run:
4) `firebase deploy`

Answer (score -1):

Don't miss to put prod dependencies in dependencies key and not devDependencies in package.json